# Create all possible sentence from an Array of words

Tags: php, arrays

From this Array of Words

```
$words = ['THIS', 'IS', 'AN', 'EXAMPLE'];
```

I want to make Sentences like the following:

```
$sentences = [
    'THIS IS AN EXAMPLE',
    'THIS IS AN',
    'THIS IS',
    'THIS'
];
```

Also i would like to know how to reverse the `ORDER` of it,

Like to start from `THIS` to `EXAMPLE` like `'THIS IS AN EXAMPLE'`

Or to start from `EXAMPLE` to `THIS` like `'EXAMPLE AN IS THIS'`

or getting both from Forward to Backward and from Backward to Forward so i get

```
$sentences = [
    'THIS IS AN EXAMPLE',
    'THIS IS AN',
    'THIS IS',
    'THIS',
    `EXAMPLE AN IS THIS`,
    `EXAMPLE AN IS`,
    `EXAMPLE AN`,
    `EXAMPLE`
];
```

What I've tried was

```
    $sentences = [];
    $words = ['THIS', 'IS', 'AN', 'EXAMPLE'];
    $wordscount = count($words);
    $i = 1;
    while ($i < $wordscount) {
        $newword = '';
        foreach ($words as $word) {
            $newword .= "$word ";
        }
        while (in_array($newword, $sentences)) {
            $newword = explode(' ', $newword);
            $newword = array_pop($newword);
            $newword = implode(' ', $newword);
            echo "$newword <br>";
        }
        $sentences[] = $newword;
        $i++;
    }
print_r($sentences);
```

and it is incomplete Because when i load the page the Web Browser and FastCGI CPU Usage Jumps to 50% for each one And page shows me Memory Usage Problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

1. Create a loop which will iterate the total amount of items in the array.
2. Reduce the array by the iteration value and implode it into a return
   array.

Then do the same again but simply with a reversed array and merge them both.

**For example:**

```
<?php
function join_words($words) {
    $return = [];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($words); $i++) {
        $return[] = implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $i+1));
    }
    return $return;
}

$words = ['THIS', 'IS', 'AN', 'EXAMPLE'];

$result = [];
$result = array_merge($result, join_words($words));
$result = array_merge($result, join_words(array_reverse($words)));

print_r($result);
```

https://3v4l.org/vG7tj

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => THIS
    [1] => THIS IS
    [2] => THIS IS AN
    [3] => THIS IS AN EXAMPLE
    [4] => EXAMPLE
    [5] => EXAMPLE AN
    [6] => EXAMPLE AN IS
    [7] => EXAMPLE AN IS THIS
)
```

---

If you want the exact output as shown, you should reverse the array before merging it.

```
$result = [];
$result = array_merge($result, array_reverse(join_words($words)));
$result = array_merge($result, array_reverse(join_words(array_reverse($words))));
```

https://3v4l.org/R4LDo

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => THIS IS AN EXAMPLE
    [1] => THIS IS AN
    [2] => THIS IS
    [3] => THIS
    [4] => EXAMPLE AN IS THIS
    [5] => EXAMPLE AN IS
    [6] => EXAMPLE AN
    [7] => EXAMPLE
)
```

Comment: In case i wanted the exact values as i have written `[0] => THIS IS AN EXAMPLE ~ [3] => THIS`, Do i just change it to be negative instead of positive? I'll check how array_slice() works now.

Comment: You would be better off reversing the array before merging it.